# Serve via containerized Nginx files from php-fpm container?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

My app files are located in `phpfpm` container and I need to serve them through `nginx`. I want to avoid mounting the same files in two containers, so I'm trying to figure out a way to serve them only from one, `phpfpm`, container. When I use ***reverse proxy to other containers***:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name myapp.test;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://phpfpm:900;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I get ***502 Bad Gateway*** error with the following error log record:

> 1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: myapp.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:9000/", host: "myapp.test"

I guess it's because `phpfpm` container is not a HTTP server.

So, alternatively, I try using `fastcgi_pass` like so:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name myapp.test;

    root /app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

This serves `*.php` files as expected, but doesn't serve other files, namely static content.

How do I make`nginx` serve both `.php` and static files from my `phpfpm` container?

Here's my *docker-compose.yml*:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  phpfpm:
    image: "php-fpm:7.3"
    volumes:
      - ./site:/app
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  nginx:
    image: "nginx:1.17"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/app.conf:/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues:

- You did not mount your static content into your Nginx container, therefore it cannot be served. Add this volume to your container

```
./site/public/:/var/www/html/public/:ro
```

- You need to setup your Nginx config in order to serve this static content. You may try this one

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name myapp.test;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that I started tinkering with this exactly because I wanted to avoid mounting the same app files twice, I wanted to serve everything from only one, php-fpm, in this case, container. However, the configuration provided in your answer is very useful for me, so I'm upvoting it!